# Relation between Centraliser of a and b

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ are elements belongs to group $G$ such that $b= a^k$   i.e  $b$ belongs to subgroup generated by $a$. We can easily prove that Centraliser of $a$  is subset of Centraliser of $b$ ,where $b$ belongs to subgroup generated by $a$. But I want to know is Centraliser of $a =$ Centraliser of $b$ in any condition?  What happen if I choose such $b$ which is generator of subgroup $\langle a\rangle$?

Comment: If $b$ is the generator of $\left< a \right>$ then $a=b^l$ for some $l$, so the centralisers would be equal from symmetry reasons.

Comment: And what if b is not generator of <a> ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is false: take $G=D_8$, the dihedral group on four vertices, where $\sigma$ is the rotation and $\tau$ the reflection. then $\sigma^2$ commutes with every element of $D_8$, but $\sigma$ does not, thus their centralisers are different.

However, as I noted in my comment, the centralisers would be equal if $b$ generates $\left< a \right>$, that is $gcd(|a|, l) = 1$ where $l$ is the integer such that $a^l = b$

Comment: I think here gcd (|a| , k )=1 with k is integer such that a= a^k = b { in last line of your answer} and order of a=order of b isn't it?

Comment: @alearner yes you're right. Sorry..